# Downloaded Items in Cefsharp 75 are not showing icons anymore

Tags: c#, cefsharp

So with the introduction of the CefSharp version 75 from MyGet has changed how the scheme handler handles items such as file icons of the downloaded items from the browser. With CefSharp 74 I had no problem like this all downloaded items would show their icons on my downloads.html page after download completion so now this doesn't even happen. The downloads.html loads perfectly but doesn't show my recent downloads nor does it show their file icons. The downloaded items still download with no problems but i need it back to how it was before.

I have tried implementing the IResourceHandler with the new Open, Read, and Skip portions to the code. And editing them to make them work with the code everything loads perfect from my scheme however no file icons of downloaded items are being shown.

Old scheme handler
//

```
    private MemoryStream GetFileIcon(string name, IconReader.IconSize size)
    {
        Icon icon = IconReader.GetFileIcon(name, size, false);
        using (icon)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = icon.ToBitmap();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return ms;
        }
    }

    public bool ProcessRequest(IRequest request, ICallback callback)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(request.Url);
        string fileName = uri.AbsolutePath;

        if (uri.Host == "storage")
        {
            fileName = appPath + uri.Host + fileName;
            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    using (callback)
                    {
                        //var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(resource);
                        //stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                        FileStream fStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                        mimeType = ResourceHandler.GetMimeType(Path.GetExtension(fileName));
                        stream = fStream;
                        callback.Continue();
                    }
                });

                return true;
            }
        }

        if (uri.Host == "fileicon")
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                using (callback)
                {
                    stream = GetFileIcon(fileName, IconReader.IconSize.Large);
                    mimeType = ResourceHandler.GetMimeType(".png");
                    callback.Continue();
                }
            });
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    public bool ReadResponse(Stream dataOut, out int bytesRead, ICallback callback)
    {
        //Dispose the callback as it's an unmanaged resource, we don't need it in this case
        callback.Dispose();

        if (stream == null)
        {
            bytesRead = 0;
            return false;
        }

        //Data out represents an underlying buffer (typically 32kb in size).
        byte[] buffer = new byte[dataOut.Length];
        bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        dataOut.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        return bytesRead > 0;
    }
}}
```

New scheme handler
//

```
    public bool Open(IRequest request, out bool handleRequest, ICallback callback)
    {
        handleRequest = false;
        return false;
    }

    public bool Skip(long bytesToSkip, out long bytesSkipped, IResourceSkipCallback callback)
    {
        bytesSkipped = 0;
        callback.Continue(bytesSkipped);
        return true;
    }

    public bool Read(Stream dataOut, out int bytesRead, IResourceReadCallback callback)
    {
        bytesRead = -1;
        return false;
    }
```

Downloads.html code
//

```
    var $container;
    var $template;
    var timer;

    $(document).ready(function () {
    $container = $("#downloads-display");
    $template = $("#template");
    UpdateList();
    timer = setInterval(UpdateList, 500);
    });

    function formatBytes(bytes, decimals) {
    if (bytes == 0) return '0 Byte';
    var k = 1000;
    var dm = decimals + 1 || 3;
    var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'];
    var i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k));
    return (bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toPrecision(dm) + ' ' + sizes[i];
    }

    String.prototype.between = function (prefix, suffix) {
    s = this;
    var i = s.indexOf(prefix);
    if (i >= 0) {
    s = s.substring(i + prefix.length);
    }
    else {
    return '';
    }
    if (suffix) {
    i = s.indexOf(suffix);
    if (i >= 0) {
    s = s.substring(0, i);
    }
    else {
    return '';
    }
    }
    return s;
    }

    Date.prototype.format = function (format) //author: meizz
    {
    var o = {
    "M+": this.getMonth() + 1, //month
    "d+": this.getDate(),    //day
    "h+": this.getHours(),   //hour
    "m+": this.getMinutes(), //minute
    "s+": this.getSeconds(), //second
    "q+": Math.floor((this.getMonth() + 3) / 3),  //quarter
    "S": this.getMilliseconds() //millisecond
    }

    if (/(y+)/.test(format)) format = format.replace(RegExp.$1,
    (this.getFullYear() + "").substr(4 - RegExp.$1.length));
    for (var k in o) if (new RegExp("(" + k + ")").test(format))
    format = format.replace(RegExp.$1,
    RegExp.$1.length == 1 ? o[k] :
    ("00" + o[k]).substr(("" + o[k]).length));
    return format;
    }

    function getDate(dt) {
    return eval("new " + dt.between("/","/"));
    }

    function UpdateItem(item) {
    var $item;
    var id = "d" + item.Id;
    $item = $("#" + id);
    //Add item if it does not exist
    if ($item.length == 0) {
    $item = $($template[0].outerHTML);
    $container.prepend($item);

    // show it
    $item.removeAttr("hidden");

    // add basic stuff
    $item.attr("id", id);
    $item.find("a.cancel").click(function () {
    host.cancelDownload(item.Id);
    });

    // icon
    $item.find("img.icon").attr("src", "codernut://fileicon/" + item.SuggestedFileName);

    // name
    if (item.SuggestedFileName != "") $item.find("span.name").text(item.SuggestedFileName);
    $item.find("a.src-url").attr("href", item.Url).text(item.Url);
    $item.find("a.cancel").removeAttr("hidden");

    // date
    var startTime = Date.parse(item.startTime);
    $item.find("div.since").text(startTime.format("MM.dd.yyyy"));
    $item.find("div.date").text(startTime.format("hh:mm:ss"));
    }
    var progress = "";
    if (item.IsInProgress) {
    progress = formatBytes(item.CurrentSpeed) + "/s - " + formatBytes(item.ReceivedBytes, 2);
    if (item.TotalBytes > 0) progress += " of " + formatBytes(item.TotalBytes, 2);
    if (item.PercentComplete > 0) progress += " (" + item.PercentComplete + "%)";
    } else {
    if (item.IsComplete) progress = "Complete";
    else if (item.IsCancelled) progress = "Cancelled";
    $item.find("a.cancel").attr("hidden","");
    }
    $item.find("span.status").text(progress);
    }

    function UpdateList() {
    host.getDownloads().then(function (res) {
    var list = JSON.parse(res);
    $.each(list, function (key, item) {
    UpdateItem(item.v);
    });
    });
    }
</script>
```

No of the things Amaitland recommended worked for me.

Comment: Code seems incomplete, post the whole class. You are using a nightly developer build, it's not production ready, please wait for the pre release at least before upgrading.